# How do I fix Fortify static scan issue related to Open Redirect in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, static-analysis, fortify, software-quality

I have an application that has a help page with a horizontal menu on top of it.
Once the user clicks on the `Help` link within the menu the following controller gets invoked and the user is taken to a page that is NOT within my current application but is part of another application that another department within my organization owns.

In order to fix the issue I added a new method `isValidSite()` and added some checks to validate the url hoping that Fortify will stop complaining about it but no luck.

Please guide.

**Fortify S3 Error:**

```
The file HelpController.java passes unvalidated data to an HTTP redirect function on line 26: return "redirect:" + helpUrl;. 
Allowing unvalidated input to control the URL used in a redirect can aid phishing attacks.
```

**HelpController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/help.htm")
public class HelpController {

    private static String helpUrl = "http://some.other.app.within.my.org/help-page.html";
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("HelpController.class");

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected String handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (isValidSite()) {
            log.info("Redirecting to: " + helpUrl);
            return "redirect:" + helpUrl;
        }
        log.error("URL should have my.org within it: " + helpUrl);
        return "errors/runtime-error";
    }

    //ADDED THIS TO FIX THE FORTIFY SCAN ISSUE, BUT NO LUCK :(
    private boolean isValidSite() {
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(helpUrl) && helpUrl.contains("my.org");
    }

}
```

Comment: I thnk Forify did not find any tainted value for helpUrl. If you pass helpUrl as a parameter to isValideSite ? Do it solve the problem ? (I know this is not mandatory, but If you want to have a green bullet point, this could be a solution :))